# Vee validate useForm with nested data

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have an object with some nested properties that I would like to bind to a form in vee validate using the composition api. This is what I'm doing right now but it feels pretty verbose. Can I utilize `useForm` to construct the data model and bind it to the UI?

This is what I have now:

```
<input type="text" v-model="field1" />
<input type="text" v-model="field2" />
<input type="text" v-model="field3" />
```

```
interface MyForm {
    field1: string;
    nested: { field2: string; field3: string; }
}

useForm({
   validationSchema: { /* rules */ }
})

const { value: field1 } = useField<string>('field1')
const { value: field2 } = useField<string>('field2')
const { value: field3 } = useField<string>('field3')

// before sent to backend, the form needs to be reconstructed:
const form = computed<MyForm>(() => ({ field1, nested: { field2, field3 } }))

return { field1, field2, field3 }
```

What I'm after is something like:

```
<input type="text" v-model="field1" />
<input type="text" v-model="nested.field2" />
<input type="text" v-model="nested.field3" />
```

```
interface MyForm {
    field1: string;
    nested: { field2: string; field3: string; }
}

const {values} = useForm({
   initialValues: { field1: '', nested: { field2: '', field3: '' } }
   validationSchema: { /* rules */ }
})

return { ...toRefs(values) }
```

But according to the specification, values shouldn't be mutated. Do I have any options to my approach? I would like the complete form to be exposed to the UI and available as a `Ref` that I can pass along to my backend.

Comment: This is possible. See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-nested-fields-in-vee-validate-form?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.vue).

Comment: @tony19 Thanks, although it's working with your utility function, rather than out of the box. But I guess that answers my question :)

Comment: Hi. I am currently run into this kind of problem. Maybe you can please check on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77864680/vee-validate-and-yup-with-dynamic-input-fields-not-validating-and-showing-errors